# webhooks not creating a new firestore document when stripe payment is successful or canceled

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm using the following flow:

user pays or cancels a stripe order > a new document is created with the user's email address> the trigger mail sends an email to the user.

I'm using the Firebase trigger mail extension. ( I tested it by creating a document manually and it works )

In the stripe dashboard, I've added the webhook endpoints to `handleStripePayments` & `handleStripePayments` function's URL & passed the following events: `payment_intent.succeeded` & `payment_intent.canceled`

I tried a test payment in the stripe test mode. But it didn't create a new document.

Here's my code

I am not using any .env to store the API key for now.

index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const { Firestore } = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const stripe = require('stripe');


admin.initializeApp();
const db = new Firestore();
const stripeClient = new stripe('API key here'); 


exports.handleStripePaymentSuccess = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

  try {
    if (req.body.type === 'payment_intent.succeeded') {
      const paymentIntentId = req.body.data.object.id;
      const paymentIntent = await stripeClient.paymentIntents.retrieve(paymentIntentId);

      const customerEmail = paymentIntent.charges.data[0].billing_details.email;
      const username = extractUsernameFromEmail(customerEmail);

      const html=`some HTML code here`

      const message = {
        subject: 'Congratulations on Your Purchase of the Job Application Toolkit!',
        text: `Dear, ${username}`,
        html: `${html}`,
      };



      await db.collection('mail').add({
        to: customerEmail,
        message: message,
      });

      res.status(200).send('Email document added successfully.');
    } else {
      return functions.handleStripePaymentFailure(req, res);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error('Error handling Stripe event:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});

exports.handleStripePaymentFailure = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (req.body.type === 'payment_intent.canceled') {
        const paymentIntentId = req.body.data.object.id;
        const paymentIntent = await stripeClient.paymentIntents.retrieve(paymentIntentId);
  
        const customerEmail = paymentIntent.charges.data[0].billing_details.email;
  
        const recipients = [customerEmail];
        const username = extractUsernameFromEmail(customerEmail);

        const html=`some HTML code here`

        const message = {
          subject: 'Complete Your Job Application Toolkit Purchase Today!',
          text: `Dear, ${username}`,
          html: `${html}`,
        };
  
  
        await db.collection('mail').add({
          to: recipients,
          message: message,
        });
  
        res.status(200).send('Email document added successfully.');
      }

  } catch (error) {
    functions.logger.error('Error handling Stripe payment failure:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
function extractUsernameFromEmail(email) {
    const atIndex = email.indexOf('@');
    return atIndex !== -1 ? email.substring(0, atIndex) : email;
  }
```

Comment: Something I spotted, which may not be the problem, but you should definitely be careful of, is `const customerEmail = paymentIntent.charges.data[0].billing_details.email`. Stripe removed the `charges` array a while back, in favour of a `latest_charge` object. Depending on your API version, you may not have a `charges` array. Technically, it could be the reason for your issue: i.e. this returns null and breaks your `extractUsernameFromEmail` function. But that's a bit of a longshot. Anyways, keep that in mind, and try to log your code to see exactly how far it gets without creating a Document

Comment: Is calling `functions.handleStripePaymentFailure(req, res)` even valid? If anything, you'd want to name the callback you pass to `onRequest` for `handleStripePaymentFailure` and then call it directly (i.e. `const handleStripePaymentFailureCallback = async (req, res) => {}`, then use it in `exports.handleStripePaymentFailure = functions.https.onRequest(handleStripePaymentFailureCallback)` and chain it using `return handleStripePaymentFailureCallback(req, res)`)

Comment: @Lucky2501 Hi, thank you. Changing it to the `latest_charge` object worked. Additionally, I had to expand that string into an object :)